# jquery element filter by css

Tags: jquery

I would like to select every div that has a red background color for example.
is this possible in jquery?

```
<div style="background-color:red"></div>
<div style="background-color:white"></div>
<div style="background-color:red"></div>
<div style="background-color:yellow"></div>
```

thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$('div[style=background-color:red]');
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I answered the question in reference to the example  html above.

Comment: nothing wrong with that, just worth pointing out in case someone using this doesn't realize that. Also, if the style tag isn't formatting exactly like `background-color:red` this will not match

Comment: this doesn't really work if the color is specified in hex: `#AABBCC`, probably because of the `#`. How can we escape the `#` ?

Comment: answered my own comment: you need double backslash for escaping, and the colon (`:`) should also be escaped: `jQuery('div[style=color\\:\\#AABBCC]`

Answer (score 24):

This code also works for CSS that is **not** defined in the style attribute of the tag:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('background-color') == 'red';
});
```

Answer (score 21):

You could use the jQuery filter:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   return this.element.style['background-color'] == 'red';
});
```

But, as tvanfosson has said, the correct way would be to assign a CSS class to each of your divs, then you could call the objects using jQuery like this (which is the preferred way of working with jQuery):

```
$('.yourCSSClass');
```

Comment: That would only work if the background color is explicitly declared in the style attribute of the tag...

Comment: return this.style['background-color'] == 'red'; -  this worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Why do it the hard way?  A better solution is to use CSS classes to give your elements their styles, then you can simply use the class-based selector.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .alert {
       background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<div class="alert"></div>


$('.alert')....
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I never recommend setting in-line styles on page elements.  Assign CSS classes and control your background colors in an external CSS document.

```
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.red {background-color:red;}
.white {background-color:white;}
.yellow {background-color:yellow;}
```

Then it makes it easy to select the red ones by using: `$('div.red')`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a custom filter for that if you don't want to rely on a certain `style=xxx` attribute on the tag:

```
$('*').filter(function() { /* check the background color of this */ });
```